# SearchView inside AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, searchview

I have AlertDialog which include long list of items(List of Products), my question if its possible to create SeachView inside this AlertDialog and how, or if there is something similar?

**My AlertDialog**

```
 private void showDialogProduit(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(AjouterFactureActivity.this)
            .setAdapter(adapterProduit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    codeProduit = produitList.get(which).getCode();
                    showDialogMatierePremiere();

                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            })
            .setTitle("Selectionner Produit")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show();

}
//Get liste des Produits
private void getListProduits(){
    final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Chargement en cours...");

    final ApiService produitApi = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    Call<List<ProductLvItems>> api =produitApi.getListProduits();

    api.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProductLvItems>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductLvItems>> call, Response<List<ProductLvItems>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                List<ProductLvItems> prodList = response.body();
                produitList.AddAll(prodList);
                if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();


            }else{
                if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ProductLvItems>> call, Throwable t) {
            if (mProgressDialog.isShowing())
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();


        }
    });
}

    adapterProduit = new ProduitLvAdapter(getApplicationContext(),  produitList);
    adapterProduit.addAll(produitList);

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to have a custom view alertdialog, create the UI stuff and do the search logic.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, do you know any example?

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder#setView`